# Boto3: querying DynamoDB with multiple sort key values

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Is there any way of supplying multiple values for a DynamoDB table's Sort Key whilst doing a query in Boto3?

For a single SK value to search on, I'm doing this:

```py
    table.query(
        IndexName="my_gsi",
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('my_gsi_pk').eq({pk value}) & Key('my_gsi_sk').eq({sk value}),
        FilterExpression={filter expression}
    )
```

... which works.

However, my scenario involves searching on one of a couple of potential SK values, so I'd like to, in SQL terms, do something like this:

```
    WHERE my_gsi_pk = {pk value}
    AND   my_gsi_sk IN ({sk value 1}, {sk value 2})
```

I've looked in the Boto3 documentation in the .query() section and concentrated upon the `KeyConditionExpression` syntax but can't identify whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `query` API [does not support the `IN` operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) in the `KeyConditionExpression`.

Use the [execute_statement](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.execute_statement) API instead.  This executes a [PartiQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html) statement, which [does accept the `IN` operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html#ql-reference.select.parameters) in query operations for the Partition and Sort keys:

```py
sk = ["Foo", "Bar"]

res = client.execute_statement(
  Statement=f'SELECT * FROM "my_table"."my_gsi" WHERE my_gsi_pk = ? AND my_gsi_sk IN [{",".join(["?" for k in sk])}]',
  Parameters= [{"S": "1"}] + [{"S": k} for k in sk]
)
```

This creates a PartiQL Statement like `SELECT * FROM "my_table"."my_gsi" WHERE my_gsi_pk = ? AND my_gsi_sk IN [?, ?]` and substitution Parameters like `[{"S": "1"}, {"S": "Foo"}, {"S": "Bar"}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the PartiQL will spend much more **RCU** than the Query. You can check this by requesting ReturnConsumedCapacity = ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL