# Can I use `contains` in a query for DynamoDB GSI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am new to DynamoDB. If I make a GSI, can I do a query with KeyConditionExpression: contains (GSI, :val1) and contains(GSI, :val2)
Will it be a full scan?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "contains".  Can you give an example?  See @Maurice's  comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a Scan. The query only supports things like `begins_with`, `>=`, `<=`, `>`, `<`, `=`, or `between`.

See [Key Condition Expressions for Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not with the `Query` API, as @Maurice says.  However, you can achieve the same "query, not scan" end result with [ExecuteStatement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html) and a [PartiQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html) statement with an `IN` operator applied to the index key in question.  For example, 2 partition key values:

```sql
SELECT * from "my_table"."GSI" WHERE my_gsi_pk_key IN ['val1', 'val2']
```

It executes as a [query operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html#ql-reference.select.parameters).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72615261/1103511) has a complete example.

N.B. You have no choice but to use PartiQL here, but in general I would recommend avoiding it whilst learning DynamoDB.  The core API better forces you to learn DynamoDB's idioms and unlearn RDBMS/SQL thinking.

Comment: Not entirely sure what OP meant by the `contains` operation, but I suspect it's more like "does the SK contain x", which I don't think this PartiQL answers. Can that be done by PartQL?

Comment: @Maurice.  Fair point.  If OP needs to check for arbitrary attribute substring values, you are right that we're in scan-land.  Considering that OP is a professed newbie who misapplied `contains` to the whole index, I assumed OP needs to test for set membership.  Perhaps OP will clarify for us.